# Multiple views into single file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3 (and ST2), if I have the same file open in multiple windows they are not linked together, so changes made in one window are not reflected in the other -- unless I use "New View into File" to open the subsequent file, in which case they are linked. Even if I do use this option to create the new view, though, if I quit with both views open, when I reopen ST3, the files are no longer linked.

Is there a way to do this so that, no matter how I open the file, if both views point to the same file, they're linked? Or, can I manually link them after the fact (in which case what happens if both views are modified in different ways)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your User/Default.sublime-keymap to give you a quick way to clone files:
`{ "keys": ["ctrl+super+n"], "command": "clone_file", },`

---

**[PreventFakeClones](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PreventFakeClones)** will prevent you from accidentally opening non-linked tabs.

I attempted to modify it for what you requested, but it still does not work when first opening Sublime Text.

The author of PreventFakeClones posted:

> Instead of preventing the opening of the “fake clone”, it would be
>   nice to just close the “fake clone” and create a real clone. Problem
>   is that currently there is no way to move a “real clone” from one
>   window to another.

Comment: Hey, does this plug-in still work? I tried installing it from Github, but it didn't seem to do anything. Perhaps I did not install it correctly?

Comment: @Cerberus No idea, switched over to VSCode a few years ago. Waaay better IntelliSense & overall extensibility IMO.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. How is VSC better in those things? (The main reason I use Sublime is that I am able to write plug-ins for it; for VSC, I couldn't even begin to make a linter, it was so complex and confusing.)

Comment: @Cerberus. Same, used to dev extensions for ST and was working on an autocompletion plugin that was a huge hassle because the completions had to be provided manually via `on_query_completions`. Haven't had to do anything of the sort with VSCode; it just knows everything about my code, including types & documentation, and it perfectly refactors changes throughout entire projects.

Comment: @Cerberus Maybe ST has gotten better since then, idk. Haven't really felt like I'm missing anything with VSC, so I haven't looked into ST's updates since I switched. Also, VSC has way more options available for devs since the API is more thorough and you can create custom UIs like `Regex Workbench`, which wasn't possible with ST last I checked.

Comment: Ah, yes, what matters the most is how good existing support is for whatever languages one happens to use.